# Find name of day by year, month and day

Tags: java

If I have int year, int month, int day in Java, how to find name of day ? Is there already some functions for this ?

Comment: If you have found your answer you should accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Modern solution uses `java.time.LocalDate` and the `DayOfWeek` enum. Ex: `LocalDate.of( y , m , d ).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( … )`

Comment: LocalDate.of(year,month,day).getDayOfWeek().toString();works well in java 8 don't forget to import java.util.*;

Answer (score 50):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a pattern of `EEEE` to get the name of the day of week.

```
// Assuming that you already have this.
int year = 2011;
int month = 7;
int day = 22;

// First convert to Date. This is one of the many ways.
String dateString = String.format("%d-%d-%d", year, month, day);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d").parse(dateString);

// Then get the day of week from the Date based on specific locale.
String dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);

System.out.println(dayOfWeek); // Friday
```

Here it is wrapped all up into a nice Java class for you.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


public class DateUtility
{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(dayName("2015-03-05 00:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss"));
    }

    public static String dayName(String inputDate, String format){
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer!  Dont forget to `import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 16):

You can do something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/GetDaysOfTheWeekfordifferentlocale.htm) to get the names of the days of the week for different locales.

Here's the important part:

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(usersLocale);
String weekdays[] = dfs.getWeekdays();
```

That can be combined with this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

To get what you're looking for:

```
String nameOfDay = weekdays[day];
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) Object to find this.

Once you create the calendar instance you get the DAY_OF_WEEK (which is an int) then you can find the day from there)

You can use a switch statement [like so](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/DayOfWeek.shtml):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DayOfWeek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.print("Today is ");
        switch (day) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Sunday");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Monday");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Tuesday");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Wednesday");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.print("Thursday");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.print("Friday");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.print("Saturday");
        }
        System.out.print(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: and that will give you an int, not a name

Comment: that's English-only. What about German?

Comment: @Bozho, well you can change the language, or you can internationalize it, so it will pick up the locale and set it to what ever you language you prefer

Comment: That's just an example. The user can use whatever Strings they want to represent this. For an example that depends on locale, see my answer.

Comment: my point exactly - you should use what is given by the jvm rather than writing your own.

Comment: use the constants `Calendar.SUNDAY`, `Calendar.MONDAY`, ... instead of the direct values. Better use `DateFormatSymbols.getWeekdays()` to retrieve the localized names.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Instead, let [`DayOfWeek.getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) automatically localize the day-of-week name. It is a one-liner: `java.time.LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )` …or `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` etc.

Answer (score 10):

Construct a GregorianCalendar with the year, month and day, then query it to find the name of the day. Something like this:

```
int year = 1977;
int month = 2;
int dayOfMonth = 15;
Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);

int dayOfWeek = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Note that the day of week is returned as an int representing the *ordinal* of the day in the locale's week day representation. IE, in a locale where the weekday starts on Monday and ends on Sunday, a 2 would represent Tuesday, whereas if the locale weekday starts on Sunday then that same 2 would represent Monday.

***Edit***

And since there is alot of answer editing going on, allow me to add the following:

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
String dayOfMonthStr = symbols.getWeekdays()[dayOfMonth];
```

Thought to be honest, I like the SimpleDateFormatter approach better, because it encapsulates the very same code as I've shown above. Silly me to forget all about it.

Comment: caution: month is zero-based, that will be a March 15th! (not February)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9):

The name of the week day differs per locale. So you have to use a `DateFormat` with the proper locale. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

The `Date` object can be obtained in multiple ways, including the deprecated `Date(..)` constructor, the `Calendar.set(..)` methods or joda-time `DateTime`. (for the latter you can use joda-time's own `DateTimeFormat`)

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22); //Set Day of the Month, 1..31
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6); //Set month, starts with JANUARY = 0
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011); //Set year
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //Starts with Sunday, 6 = friday
```

Answer (score 3):

This kind of date-time work is easier when using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. A simple one-liner.

```
String dayOfWeek = new LocalDate( 2014, 1, 2 ).dayOfWeek().getAsText( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );

System.out.println( "dayOfWeek: " + dayOfWeek );
```

When run…

```
dayOfWeek: Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new GregorianCalendar().setTime(new Date()).get(DAY_OF_WEEK)
```

That gives you a number, `Calendar.SUNDAY == 1`,  `Calendar.MONDAY == 2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a rather long process with the JDK. [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) may be a better choice (I haven't used it).

First, you get a `Calendar` object, so that you can construct a date from day/month/year/timezone. Do not use one of the deprecated `Date` constructors.

Then get a `Date` object from that calendar, and pass it to `SimpleDateFormat`. Note that the format objects are not threadsafe.

```
  // by default, this Calendar object will have the current timezone
  Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(2011, 6, 22);

  // this formatter will have the current locale
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

  System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```