# Java - Formatting and get name of day: Date object

Tags: java, date, format

All

When I define a date object it automatically assumes it's MM/dd/YYYY, however I enter it as dd/MM/yyyy.

```
Date d1 = new Date("5/12/2015 10:30:00");
```

When I get the name of the day from that date it gives me the name of May 12 (Tuesday) instead of the name of december 5 (Saturday).

```
dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(d1);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Kindly refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6789565/1728206).

Comment: @Tjekkles Be careful about confusing `YYYY` with `yyyy` as in your first sentence. They have different meanings as coded parsing patterns.

Comment: And a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5270272/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333099/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` formatter for that.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date newDate = format.parse("05/12/2015");
```

With that you can define your own format-strings!

Comment: One question: when I add a time to it (hh:mm:ss) it assumes its AM/PM, but I want 12:00:05 to be noon, not convert it to 00:00:05, how can I prevent this?